# why is my icon function not working in my code?

Tags: python, discord.py

i made an embed using a website, and wanted the icon to show the interaction users pfp, but it wont work. code:

```
@client.tree.command(name="announce", description="used to announce messages into any channel of the server")
async def name(interaction: discord.Interaction, channel: discord.TextChannel, msg: str, title: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**{title}**",
                      description=f"{msg}",
                      colour=0xf5d400)
    
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()


    embed.set_author(name=f"{interaction.user}",
                     icon_url="Interaction.user.avatar")

    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/021/282/254/original/be-careful-sign-symbol-exclamation-mark-in-yellow-free-png.png")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"Sent by {interaction.user}")

    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Your announcement has been sent to <#{channel.id}> successfully.",ephemeral=True)
```

i tried to switch the "icon_url" to different things, but it wouldnt work no matter what. whenever i remove it the command runs, but with that part in the code does not run

Comment: `interaction.user.avatar` shouldn't be in quotes. And `I` should be `i`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: use `icon_url=interaction.user.avatar.url`. And as @Barmar said, don‘t put it in quotes, you want to access the object, but you‘re using strings rn